# Mac OS X > pfctl > How to limit Bandwidth for a specific port?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, bandwidth

I need to limit the Bandwidth of our Apache Server (which runs on port 80 by default).

It was easy with **ipfw** as follows:

```
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 100Kbytes/s 
sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 src-port 80
```

But, ipfw has been discontinued in newer versions of Max OS X.

Do we have a way to do this using **pfctl** (or any other similar tool) ?

I searched the Web, but no luck ! (as the docs are very weird)